# WebService Concurrency on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, concurrency

I have a simple app and I want to use it as webservice.

My problem is that I can't receive more than 1 request at the same time.

Apparently, the requests are enqueued and executed one by one. So, if I make 2 requests on the same URL, the second has to wait for the first one.

I've already tried to use Unicorn, Puma and Thin to enable concurrency on the requests, but it seems to keep queuing the requests by URL.

**Example:**

- I make the request 1 at localhost:3000/example
- I make another request at localhost:3000/another_example
- I make the last request at localhost:3000/example

The first and second requests are executed concurrently, but the last one (that has the same URL that the first) has to wait for the first to finish.

Unicorn, Puma and Thin enable concurrency, but on different URLs.

NOTES:

I added on my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.allow_concurrency = true
```

I'm running the app with:

```
rails s Puma
```

How can I perform my requests concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, each Puma/Thin/Unicorn/Passenger/Webrick workers houses a single Rails app instance (or Sinatra app instance, etc) per Ruby process. So it's 1 web worker = 1 app instance = 1 Ruby process.

Each request blocks the process until the response is ready. So it's usually 1 request per process.

Ruby itself has the so called "GIL" (Global Interpreter Lock) which blocks execution of multiple threads because of C extensions lack of thread-safe controles such as mutexes and semaphores. It means that threads won't run concurrently. In practice, they "can". I/O operations can block execution waiting for a response. For example, reading a file or waiting response from a network socket. In this case, Ruby allow another thread to resume until the I/O operation of the previous thread finishes.

But Rails used to have a single block of execution per request as well, it's own lock. But in Rails 3, they added thread-safe controls through the Rails code to ensure it could run in JRuby for example. And in Rails 4 they decided to have the thread-safe controls on by default.

In theory this means that more than one request can run in parallel even in Ruby MRI (as it supports native threads since 1.9). In practice one request can run while another is waiting for a database process to return for example. So you should see a few more requests running in parallel. If your example is CPU bound (more internal processing than I/O blocks) the effect should be as if the requests are running one after the other. Now, if you have more I/O blocks (as waiting for a large SQL select to return), you should see it running more in parallel (not completely though).

You will see parallel requests more often if you use a virtual machine with not only native threads but no Global Interpreter Lock, such is the case of JRuby. So I recommend using JRuby with Puma.

Puma and Passenger are both multi-threaded. Unicorn is fork-based. Thin is Eventmachine based. I'd personally recommend testing Passenger as well.

- http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html
- https://bearmetal.eu/theden/how-do-i-know-whether-my-rails-app-is-thread-safe-or-not/

Comment: Passenger Enterprise/Pro is multi-threaded. However, Passenger Open Source is multi-process only. This is a big difference in terms of OS resources management in each version when using multiple workers.